# Which version of Java do I need for Tomcat 6?

Tags: tomcat, java

when installing Tomcat 6 (the latest version), it asks for the Java install directory, fair enough. But it seems to want Java version 5, which Sun is apparently end-of-life'ing, so for our environment that's not A Good Thing.

Here's its prompt, you can see it asks for version 5.0:

[image: Tomcat]

I guess what I'm asking is, can I run it against Java 6? I looked all over the tomcat website and found no mention of compatible java versions.

Thanks a lot

Comment: I found at least two guys say it works with java 6:
http://www.nabble.com/Re:-Tomcat-and-Java6-p8728729.html
http://marakana.com/blog/cool-tech/tomcat-on-java-6.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By looking at http://www.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-6/v6.0.20/ we can read

```
Tomcat 6.0 requires JRE 5.0. Read the RELEASE-NOTES and the RUNNING.txt file in the distribution for more details.
```

If you open RELEASE-NOTES you will see

```
===================
Dependency Changes:
===================
Tomcat 6.0 is designed to run on JSE 5.0 and later.
```

So it's should be fine.

Comment: congratulations to apache/tomcat for making this information so easy to find.

Comment: I'm hearing you roy. I would have expected something like "we test and offer paid support against java version X, Y, Z"

Comment: You're right, if they could start by changing "Tomcat 6.0 requires JRE 5.0" by "Tomcat 6.0 requires JRE 5.0 or later" in all docs it would be a nice start.

Comment: Well, with some very limited testing, it seems to work fine with java 6. Thanks a lot

Comment: I couldn't get Java 10 to work with Tomcat 7 for what it's worth. This is despite http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html  saying Tomcat 7 works with Java 6 and later :/

Answer (score 3):

I have run Tomcat 6.x on various releases of OpenJDK 7 without a hitch. The better message would have been that Tomcat 6.x cannot run on Java 1.4.x or older releases